# A Wilson prime is a prime p such that (p−1)!≡−1 mod p^2. Write a procedure which determines all Wilson primes less than10^4

Tags: prime-numbers

I try to use the for loop to solve this question, but it does not work. And here is what I did.

```
For[p = 2,p<=10000,(p-1)! = -1 mod (p^2),Print[p]]
```

I am not sure how to describe "(p−1)!≡−1 mod p^2" in Mathematica. Could you give me some suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: `Equal` is `==` in infix form, not `=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably faster to do a divisibility test than actually calculate the modulus:

```
Do[If[PrimeQ[p] && Divisible[(p - 1)! + 1, p^2], Sow[p]], {p, 10^4}] // Reap // Last

(*    {{5, 13, 563}}    *)
```

`For` is poor style in Mathematica. Use `Do` or `Table` instead.

`Print` is only useful if you want to read the results from the screen. If you want to use the results in further calculations, a `Sow`/`Reap` combination is preferrable: [Collecting Expressions during Evaluation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html#8044).

Answer (score 5):

```
Select[Range[10000], Mod[(# - 1)! + 1, #^2] == 0 &]
```

But I think we should test only the prime number,so we modified the above code.

```
Select[Prime[Range[10000]], Mod[(# - 1)! + 1, #^2] == 0 &]
(* {5, 13, 563} *)
```

Comment: `Select[Range[10^5], 
  PrimeQ[#] && Mod[(# - 1)! + 1, #^2] == 0 &] // AbsoluteTiming`